# Cursor jumps around on Macbook Pro mid-2010, without trackpad installed

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse, trackpad, software, cursor

to solve my erratic cursor on my mid-2010 MacBook Pro, I brought my computer to the local apple store and had the trackpad completely uninstalled. Does anybody know what it means for the trackpad to completely uninstalled? Ok, anyways I'm going to post a question I never got a reply to on the apple support page. Here it goes.

Macbook Pro mid 2010 15 inch
Processor: 2.4 GHz Intel Core i5
Memory: 8 GB
Software: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 256 MB

Ok all the problems started two years ago, after I bought the computer. For the first four months everything was all dandy until I notices that my cursor behaving erratically, even though I was using a mouse. So I thought that the problem was a bulging battery, even though the trackpad still appeared normal. So using the universal access preferences, I completely turned off the trackpad completely, (using the option to switch off the trackpad when a mouse was in use).

BTW, the mouse was new and corded; used on other computers, it behaved normally.

Another year and a half goes by, and I start encountering another problem. This time the computer would occasionally power off. This occurred randomly, with no preference as to which program or application was more susceptible. In the console it read as a kernel panic, (I had no idea what that meant) and as usual I ignored the problem, blaming it on a faulty battery that would soon need to be replaced. Finally one day I mustered up the courage to go to my peach mac provider and understand the problem.

I was duly shocked to hear green checks all round. Everything was fine in fact (including the battery) expect the trackpad; a problem, which employees assured me, was common enough. Trackpads on my type of macbook pro would occasionally go haywire and just screw up. The estimate for replacement was $170, which was too deep for my pocket, so I politely declined and asked for any other solution. After some prodding, they said they could "unscrew" the trackpad, and I was all ears for this, because I gotten used to working without one. So the trackpad was uninstalled and I returned happy to my house. Also, they told me that a kernel panic was a software issue that could be the fault of the OS X or a third party application.

I forgot to mention, along with the panics, came the general erratic behavior of the cursor. Not as before, where the cursor would go around clicking and dragging mayhem everywhere, but just general skipping around and inaccuracy. So to solve this problem, I bought a new mouse. It was a G100s.

Set to discover the reason behind the kernel panics, I did everything I could to solve the problem. In fact I deleted my entire hard-drive and reinstalled the OS and backed-up the backup. After this, the kernel panics have not yet reoccured (will edit if one does) but the mouse foolishness did. I was afraid to reset the VRAM or whatever you call it, since it also deletes the error log, something that I may want to keep as proof for any techies that may have the solution to the problem.

Once, I started up in safe mode and the mouse worked fine, in fact gloriously accurate, however I was not and could not perform any cpu intensive programs to heat things up. I say this because the mouse problem only occurs after about 30 minutes on the computer. I notice that the general mouse performance is subpar compared to using it on another computer.

If anyone can provide any possible solutions or anything please feel free. And I forgot to include a vital piece of information or something is written in a confusing manner, tell me.

Comment: I am not sure I wold know what is the question now? Could you provide us with a Executive summary please.

Comment: It might not be the Mouse at all but your Graphics card! To test..does it do that with external graphics card only ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem with my 2009 MacBook Pro. I've been told by an aftermarket apple dealer that it is the graphics card. The card is damaged by overheating. The overheating is due an erratic fan. The erratic fan is caused by a damaged logic board.